# submitting a form that doesn't has an action

Tags: html, forms, http

I am trying to submit that form on the site from java. up till now i found the POST-DATA that is send using httpFox. but the problem that the form doesn't include an action that i could use. here is the link

http://tamarod.com/index.php?page=english

the data that is sent on submit is

Member_Name=&National_ID=&governerate_id=0&district_id=&Email=&Date_Of_Birth=&Submit=I+Accept

but i tried adding this line beside the url on the browser to try it but nothing happens..

Comment: 1) It's a `POST` form, not a `GET` form, so you must pass `POST`data. 2) Why are you doing this, if not to send false submissions?

Comment: The data sent on submit seems to indicate that no values are entered.

Comment: @Kolink i know it is a post form. from what are you are hinting. it seems like i am taking the wrong approach...how would i POST data of the form for submission either through URL in browser or in HTTP connection in java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. I was missing SetDoInput() and SetDoOutput() in my HttpConnection. so i can POST and GET data.